# How can I set PhpStorm file structure view to show inherited members by default

Tags: ide, phpstorm

How can I set PhpStorm file structure view to show inherited members by default (or change key binding from <kbd>Ctrl+F12</kbd> to show)?

The question pretty much says it all. 
I configured file structure to show up with <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+S</kbd>, but cannot change the default setting for show inherited and can't change the keys either.

- Is there a file, where default non editable configurations are in?
  For example there is an xml file under PHPStormRoot\config\keymaps
- What would the action be for that?
- Is there a plugin for more configurations?
- Should I consider writing a plugin myself (would I be able to change such things)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you remove the other configurations(ctrl+F12) for opening file structure, show inherited members becomes your keybinding(ctrl+alt+S).

However it can be buggy, won't open until you re open the IDE.

Also you will be delighted to know that if the method you are looking for doesn't exist it will automatically search from inherited members too.

I also removed f12 from my keymap at PHPStormRoot\config\keymaps\$YOURCONFIGFILE.xml

EDIT: Show extra info

Comment: 1) `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- that's where you edit your keymap. 2) You have to remove original shortcut in order for new one to take it over in that place as well (like you did already) 3) *"However it can be buggy, won't open until you re open the IDE"* Nope.Absolutely "nope". If edited as advised in #1 it will work just fine straight away. But surely, if you edit config file directly then yes -- it's expected behavior as config file is read only on IDE start. I have no idea why you are looking for workarounds instead of using dedicated functionality (settings screen)